# PHP Cannot use a scalar value as an array - Incrementing a session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am writing a script to place an order which will be added to a cart, I am storing the selected values for the cart as a session. Each new selection (addition to the cart) is added to a new session which is incremented by one each time.
ie.

```
$_SESSION['cart'][1]
$_SESSION['cart'][2]
$_SESSION['cart'][3]
```

I am receiving the below error and am stumped.
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in `C:\wamp\www\php\cart\carting\order.php` on line 37 -(This is the line `$_SESSION['cart'][$p] = $cartstring;`)

```
<?PHP

session_start();

 $productlist = $_POST['products']; //Form post


if (isset($productlist))    {       

    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))  {
        $p = 0;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$p];
        print $_SESSION['cart'][$p];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SESSION['cart']))   {   
        $p = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $p++;

        $product = explode('-', $productlist[1][0]);
        $productname = $product[0];
        $productprice = $product[1];
        $productqty = $productlist[1][1];
        $itemsubtotal = ($productprice * $productqty);

$cartstring = "productid-$productname-$productprice-$productqty-$itemsubtotal";
        $_SESSION['cart'][$p] = $cartstring;    //THIS IS LINE 37

    }

    }


$product1 = "Bread";
$price1 = 12;
$product2 = "Butter";
$price2 = 2;


 print '<form action="order.php" method="post">';
 print '<input type="checkbox" name="products[1][]" value="'.$product1." "."-"." ".$price1.'" />';echo $product1;
print '<input type="text" name="products[1][]" value="" />QTY';print '<br>';
print '<br>';print '<br>';
print '
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>';


?>
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($_SESSION['cart'])`. you'll probably find that it's a strin and NOT an array. `print $_SESSION['cart']` would be dumping that string. If it was an array, you'd simply get `Array` as the output.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['cart']) prints out int 0, so what im incrementing is simply adding an element value to$_SESSION['cart'] instead of creating an array ie. $_SESSION['cart'][1]

Comment: then there you go... it's an integer, and you're trying to use it as an array, hence your error.

Comment: Can you please explain why $_SESSION['cart'][$p] is the same as $_SESSION['cart'] = $p and $_SESSION['cart'][$p] is not $_SESSION['cart'][1] = $value

Comment: ANY statement which is simply `$var;` is a useless statement. It doesn't DO anything.

Comment: I am assigning $_SESSION['cart'][$p] to a value though and $p is indeed equal to a value?